# Problemas com o papeamento do springboot

Tags: spring-boot

Estou entrando no mundo do SpringBoot agora e esbarrei em um problema que acredito que seja fácil de resolver.

Segue a estrutura do meu projeto com pacotes de classes:

br.com.springboot.api

> SpringBootApplication

br.com.springboot.controller

> ClienteController

br.com.springboot.model

> Cliente

eu criei um mapeamento dentro da SpringBootApplication com o @RequestMapping, o problema é que quando eu dou um start na aplicação do jeito que tá e tento acessar esse mapeamento no browser ele não acha, mas se eu colocar as classes SpringbootApplication e ClienteController no mesmo pacote ele funciona!
Oq pode ser??

Comment: você colocou @ Controller e @ ComponentScan na classe controller?

Comment: Eu usei o @RestController logo acima da classe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve mapear seu pacote com os controllers.

```
@ComponentScan({"br.com.springboot.controller"})
public class SpringBootApplication {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, Obrigado!!